# If $\det Df(a)=0$ then $f^{-1}$ is not differentiable at $f(a)$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I thought that if $\det Df(a) = 0$, then this means that $Df(a)$ is not an isomorphism. So you can't use the Inverse Function Theorem. I don't know how to use this hypothesis.

Comment: $f^{-1}(f(x)) = x$ for all $x$. What can you conclude if $^{-1}$ is differentiable at $f(a)$?

Comment: How can you say that $f^-1 (f (x)) = x$ ? I did not understand. If I use this fact and derive, ie $f^{-1}'(f (x)) f' (x) = 1$, by the hypothesis $f '(a) = 0$. So it is not possible to give 1.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $f^{-1}$ is differentiable at $f(a)$. Consider the composition ${\rm id} = f^{-1} \circ f$ (where ${\rm id}$ represents the identity map). By the chain rule, we have
$$ I = Df^{-1}|_{f(a)} Df|_a$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix.

Taking determinants of both sides, we get
$$ 1 = \det Df^{-1}|_{f(a)} \times \det Df|_a.$$

But $\det Df|_a = 0$. So we have $1 = 0$, which is a contradiction.